# Determine whether $\sum_{1}^{\infty} (\frac{\sqrt{2n-1} \cdot \log(4n+1)}{n(n+1)})$ is converge.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinity

I have a question about infinite series;

> Determine whether the series are converges or diverges
>
> $\sum_{1}^{\infty} (\frac{\sqrt{2n-1}\cdot \log(4n+1)}{n(n+1)})$

I've just seen integral and comparison test so far, so if the answers just contain these methods, it would be nice.

My attempts;

I neither be able to integrate the function nor find a proper function to compare, but I thought if I prove that when n goes $\infty$, the function goes to 0 and the function's first derivative is less than 0 for all n in $(0,\infty)$, then the series converge.

So what do you guys think about my thought about solving the program ?, and what is the proper solution of this problem ?

Comment: "nor find a proper function to compare" Sure about that? And if the $n$th term was $$\frac{\sqrt{n}\log n}{n^2},$$ what would be the answer?

Comment: (And I understand nothing of the attempt you suggest, which result is it based on, already?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This series looks a lot like: $\sum_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n} \cdot \log(n)}{n^2}$, so we will compare against this series.

By the limit comparison test,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2n-1} \cdot \log(4n+1)}{n(n+1)}}{\frac{\sqrt{n} \cdot \log(n)}{n^2}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{2n-1} \cdot \log(4n+1)}{n(n+1)} \cdot \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n} \cdot \log(n)}$$$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{2n-1}}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \frac{n^2}{n(n+1)} \cdot \frac{\log(4n+1)}{\log(n)} = \sqrt{2} \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = \sqrt{2},$$

which is positive and finite, thus the original series converges if and only if $\sum_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n} \cdot \log(n)}{n^2}$ converges. To show this series converges, you can use the direct comparison test and the fact that $\log(n) \leq \sqrt{n}$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: But $\sum_n n^{-3/2} \log n \le \sum_n n^{-1} = \infty$ tells us nothing.

Comment: @Santiago good catch, comparing $\log(n)$ to $\sqrt{n}$ isn't good enough. Fortunately, you can also show $\log(n) \leq \sqrt[3]{n}$ for large enough $n$ as well and that should work out.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $\log n \leq \sqrt[4]{n}$, for $n \ge N_0$.